# App Review connecting to a Hosted app service

Tags: app-store, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

after a little bit of advice.  Kind of got myself into a bit of a chicken and egg situation.

So they story is, We have recently completed a major update on some mobile apps (Both iOS and Android).  These mobile apps connect to a Azure hosted app service which has also had a number of significant changes including many db structure changes.  All of which is currently live in production, so I have to release the updated app service and mobile apps at the same time.

This is where the problem comes in.  To make the apps avaliable for review with the relevent stores, I will of course mean I need to have updated the app service so that the updated apps work, but I can't update that until I can release the apps to the general user base.

Any advice on how to get the updated apps approved without breaking things for the current users?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Azure web app deployment slot to set up staging environments.

> Deploying your application to a non-production slot has the following benefits:
>
> 1.You can **validate app changes in a staging deployment slot before swapping it with the production slot**.
>
> 2.Deploying an app to a slot first and swapping it into production makes sure that all instances of the slot are warmed up before being swapped into production. This eliminates downtime when you deploy your app. The traffic redirection is seamless, and no requests are dropped because of swap operations. You can automate this entire workflow by configuring auto swap when pre-swap validation isn't needed.
>
> 3.After a swap, the slot with previously staged app now has the previous production app. If the changes swapped into the production slot aren't as you expect, **you can perform the same swap immediately to get your "last known good site" back**.

When you have updated the app service so that the updated apps work, click `swap` and it will immediately swap to production without breaking things for the current users.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) to set up staging environments.

Comment: Yeah, I had started down that track.  Where I got stuck was, how do I direct the mobile app to connect to deployment slot while the apps are being reviewed, then update the connection to use the production slot on release with out affecting existing users?